# Deleting a file in vb.net deletes the contents of the zipped folder

Tags: vb.net, zip, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file in VB.net. When I run the program using the method of deleting shown below, the file is deleted but so are the contents of the corresponding zipped file. However, when I debug step by step, the contents of the zipped file do not get deleted? It doesn't make sense, why is this happening?

```
Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a " + zippedLocation(1) + ".zip " + NewFileNames(1))
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(NewFileNames(1))
Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a " + zippedLocation(2) + ".zip " + NewFileNames(2))
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(NewFileNames(2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. You'll probably need to give 7z some time to complete the operation. In case the fixed 5 second interval is to basic, you'll need to create a function that checks if a file is being written to.

```
Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a " + zippedLocation(1) + ".zip " + NewFileNames(1))
system.threading.thread.sleep(5000) 'give 7z some time to finish the zipping (5 sec)
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(NewFileNames(1))
Shell("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a " + zippedLocation(2) + ".zip " + NewFileNames(2))
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(NewFileNames(2))
system.threading.thread.sleep(5000)
```